# Android: Gallery interfering with scale setting of ImageView

Tags: android, gallery, imageview, scaling

I have some images that are 48 pixels (or greater) in height, and 48 pixels (or greater) in width. So basically I have images that are either 48 X greater than 48, or greater than 48 x 48. I want to make some thumbnails from these images that are center cropped and NOT scaled so that they maintain image quality. I can't use:

```
setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)
```

because although it achieves the cropping I am looking for, it unfortunately scales the image. What I am trying to achieve with the crop is that it either cuts off the left & right of an image that is greater than 48 pixels in width, or the top & bottom of an image that is greater than 48 pixels in height.

I tried `ScaleType.CENTER` in an XML layout, and it seems to be exactly what I want. I'm using these images in a Gallery, so in my gallery Adapter I do:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView thumb = new ImageView(mContext);
        thumb.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
        thumb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(THUMB_SIZE, THUMB_SIZE));

        if (mPhotos != null) {
            String imageUrl = mPhotos.get(position).getPhotoHref();
            imageUrl = imageUrl.replaceAll(mPattern, mFormat);
            ImageManager.instance().displayImage(imageUrl, mContext, thumb, DefaultThumbId);
        } else {
            thumb.setImageResource(DefaultThumbId);
        }

        return thumb;
    }
```

but for some reason, the entire image is shown, but scaled way down. It works perfect in an XML layout, but not when I do this in code and feed it to a `Gallery`. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually not a Gallery problem, the images I was downloading weren't being scaled properly, so they were coming in with a max width/height that was the same size as the view, instead of a min width/height to achieve what I wanted here. I download at the proper size now and setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP) works properly.